srcset and sizes always download the biggest
Here's the code
<img class="rounded-full w-[60px] h-[60px] sm:w-[65px] sm:h-[65px]" srcset="1.jpg 60w, 2.jpg 65w, https://cdn.com/s/files/3.jpg 1000w, 4.jpg 2500w" sizes="(max-width: 511px) 60w, 65w">

I expect it to download 2.jpg, but instead it downloads 4.jpg.  However, 4.jpg
Why 2500vw is downloaded while I put 65w in sizes. The viewport I'm checking it with is 1500px.

Could you show us the actual CSS that is produced?

It doesn't look like you have your sizes attribute set up correctly. This article should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

You should not use w as the unit in sizes.
Correct syntax:
<img class="rounded-full w-[60px] h-[60px] sm:w-[65px] sm:h-[65px]" 
srcset="1.jpg 60w, 2.jpg 65w, https://cdn.com/s/files/3.jpg 1000w, 4.jpg 2500w" 
sizes="(max-width: 511px) 60px, 65px">

